# Use of ISB in STM32F4xx HAL function FLASH_Program_DoubleWord

Tags: stm32, flash

The following lines of code are taken from `Flash_Program_DoubleWord(uint32_t Address, uint64_t Data)` function in stm32f4xx_hal_flash.c

```
*(__IO uint32_t*)Address = (uint32_t)Data;

  /* Barrier to ensure programming is performed in 2 steps, in right order
    (independently of compiler optimization behavior) */
  __ISB();

  /* Program second word */
  *(__IO uint32_t*)(Address+4) = (uint32_t)(Data >> 32);
```

I have two questions regarding the use of __ISB() here

1. Why not writing the 64-bit value using one line of code, i.e.,
   `*(__IO uint64_t*)Address = Data;`?
2. If the write is performed as two 32-bit operations, why the write has to be done in order? Would it matter if the most significant word was written first then the least significant word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The reason reads in the code comments. If you tried to do what you propose, depending on which compiler and which optimization level you use, it may not work properly. A 64-bit variable is not a native data type on a 32-bit CPU and how they are handled is implementation-specific. So writing a 64-bit variable is not atomic on a 32-bit CPU, and any compiler can handle it in any way they want, which might not be compatible how it needs to be written to flash such as two 32-bit writes, or there could be some discrepancy between compilers which part to write first and to which address. However, if you tried that, it might just work in some cases, with some compilers, and with some compiler optimization settings.
2. It might not matter, but again, it is a good idea to force the code to do it in identical fashion in all cases, and you anyway need to pick which 32-bit word you want to write first, so why not pick the most logical order and write the LSB word to address+0 and MSB word to address+4.